# Fade away at top - CALayer mask for UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview, uiscrollview, calayer

I have a UIScrollView and I want to make it fading away at the top only.
The rest would be solid, like I have it at the picture.
Just to be clear, I don't want the content to be fading, I want the whole scrollview to fade.
The scrollView itself is solidly transparent, but I want that at some point it vanishes...
Is this even possible?

[image: How I want it...]

I hope that this is clear enough... If I can make it any clearer please write me a comment.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to work with it. I looked up some tutorials on gradients, but couldn't find anything dealing with "fading away an object"...

Comment: check this --> http://tumbljack.com/post/188089679/gpu-accelerated-awesomeness-with-cagradientlayer?c5b12fb0

Comment: In the sample they animate the gradient by building a CABasicAnimation, but you can implicitly animate the change as well, by just passing a new array of colors to the gradient layer's colors property. Use implicit animations unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "fade to transparent" what colour is behind the transparency? Is it a black background that will show through?

If so then just stick a UIImageView over the top of the UIScrollView and put an image in there that contains a gradient from 0% opacity to 100% opacity of the background colour.

That way anything that moves up underneath it will looks like it's fading into the background.